# AWS SAM Template setting environment specific variables

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am trying to configure a Lambda function's S3 policy bucket that is environment specific. I would like to be able to pass a variable during either "sam package" or "sam deploy" specifying "dev", "test" or "prod". The variable would be used in the template.yaml file to select environment specific settings:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  image-processing


Resources:
  ImageProcessingFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/image-processing.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: .
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 300
      Policies:
        S3CrudPolicy:
          BucketName: dev-bucket-name  <-- change this to dev, test or prod
```

How can I achieve this using Parameters and or Variables? Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `—parameter-overrides` in your `sam deploy` command.

[sam deploy cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html)

Let me demonstrate how:

In your template.yaml:

```
Parameters:
Env:
    Type: String

S3Bucket:
    Type: String

Resources:

ImageProcessingFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/image-processing.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: .
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 300
      Policies:
        S3CrudPolicy:
          BucketName: !Sub "${Env}-${S3Bucket}"
```

Then execute:

```
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name yourstack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameter-overrides Env=dev S3Bucket=bucket-name
```

If you want to pass your parameters from a `.json` file per env you should consider using `cross-env ENV=dev` to pass your `Env` variable and then using `gulp` or whatever to execute your `sam deploy --parameter-overrides` command while passing your json file according to your `Env` variable (process.env.ENV) (converted to how parameters overrides pattern ) as parameter-overrides params.

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that it's: `--parameter-overrides`, parameter singular.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is written correctly in other parts of my answer.

Comment: Indentation problem here (loathe to fix it)?

Comment: **Is this still the latest and greatest way of doing it?** I just seams too complicated to still be the common way of doing such a common thing. I just run into  problems, trying to combine CLI and samtemplate.yaml, as someone described here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/5169#issuecomment-1548825825 (TL;DR: not working)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `Parameters` section of the template. Check out the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html). You can then use the `--parameter-overrides` flag with the `sam deploy` command.